# Rails: Optimize Active Record query instead of looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Event
  has_many :keywords, :through => :event_keywords
end

class User 
  has_many :keywords, :through => :user_keywords
end
```

I have a User method that calculates an event's relevance based on the keywords it shares with a specific user:

```
User.rb

def calculate_event_relevance(event_id)
    event_keywords = event.keywords

    event_keywords.each do |kw|
        user_keyword_match = self.keywords.where(id: kw.id).first

        if user_keyword_match
             ## do some stuff
        end
    end
end
```

Right now, I am looping through each keyword. In the loop, I make a query to see if the user also has that keyword.

Is there a way instead to make one single query (and save it to event_keywords) that only returns the `event.keywords` that a user also has so that I don't need to loop through all of them?

Is there a query that can find which keywords a user and event have in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `event_keywords` and `user_keywords` are both arrays, you can use the `&` on the array to get the values that are present in both.

For example,

```
[1,2,3,4,5,9] & [5,6,7,8,9] #=> [5, 9]
```

In this case, 5 and 9 are present in both arrays so they are returned as a result.

In your case, you can do something like

```
share_keywords = event.keywords & self.keywords
```

To return an array with all the keywords shared between event and user. Then you can iterate through that and do what you need to do.

Comment: thanks @davidhu2000 ! That is so much easier than I thought :)